# Why is my cursor jumping in emacs nrepl

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

I am starting with emacs/nrepl for coding Clojure. With some commands, resulting in printing a long JSON result, the cursor jumps to somewhere in the middle of the output. M-> brings the cursor at the end, where it should be. Hitting ENTER causes it to jump back to somewhere in the middle of the previous JSON result. I can execute a command, like (+ 1 2) - the result is printed, cursor jumps back in the previous output. After the output has scrolled out of the screen everything is behaving normal again.

What could be causing this? I'v set up emacs following http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/ with cider-nrepl 0.9.0 and emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like an emacs bug, though I have had problems with emacs getting very slow when the REPL buffer is very large.

Try clearing the REPL with <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> + <kbd>Alt-o</kbd> and see if this restores the REPL to a useful state.

Comment: Much more likely Cider rather than emacs bug. Cider has it's own custom interaction mode for its REPL, rather than using the standard.

Comment: @Assen, please file a ticket here https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider and we'll see what we can do about this. @noisesmith, yeah you're right, although moving to `comint-mode` is on our agenda https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/709

Comment: Arthur - thanks, useful tip, though not a solution. @Batsov - ticket is filed

Comment: `Ctrl-c<\kbd>Alt-o` ?

Comment: clears the repl buffer, not sure why SO is not rendering the kdb tags correctly today. putting another character between the tags got it working